# GeoServer - Limit feature display SLD

Tags: geoserver, sld

I have a raster for U,V components of wind and I create a style that create wind barbs out of it.

What I would like to do is to limit the display of points (for example only to 300), in order to avoid symbols overlapping.

In fact, at minimum zoom i get the following result:

[image]

My SLD is :

```
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld ./StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>Wind</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>Wind</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>

                <Transformation>
                    <ogc:Function name="gs:RasterAsPointCollection">
                        <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                            <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:Function>
                    </ogc:Function>
                    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                        <ogc:Literal>emisphere</ogc:Literal>
                        <ogc:Literal>True</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Function>
                    <ogc:Function name="parameter">
                        <ogc:Literal>interpolation</ogc:Literal>
                        <ogc:Literal>InterpolationBilinear</ogc:Literal>
                    </ogc:Function>
                    
                </Transformation>
                 <Rule>
                   <MinScaleDenominator>300000</MinScaleDenominator>
                    <MaxScaleDenominator>350000000</MaxScaleDenominator>
               <PointSymbolizer>
                  <Graphic>
                     <Mark>
                       <WellKnownName>windbarbs://default(
                        <ogc:Function name="sqrt">
                          <ogc:Add>
                              <ogc:Mul>
                                <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                                <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                              </ogc:Mul>
                              <ogc:Mul>
                                <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                                <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                              </ogc:Mul>
                          </ogc:Add>
                         </ogc:Function>)[m/s]?emisphere=s
                        <ogc:PropertyName>emisphere</ogc:PropertyName>
                       </WellKnownName>
                          <Stroke>
                             <CssParameter name="stroke">000000</CssParameter>
                             <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                          </Stroke>
                       </Mark>
                       <Size>
                        <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
                              <!-- Value to transform -->
                             <ogc:Function name="sqrt">
                              <ogc:Add>
                                <ogc:Mul>
                                 <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                                 <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                                </ogc:Mul>
                                <ogc:Mul>
                                 <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                                 <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                                </ogc:Mul>
                              </ogc:Add>
                             </ogc:Function>
                              <ogc:Literal>8</ogc:Literal>
                              <ogc:Literal>1.543333332</ogc:Literal>
                              <ogc:Literal>32</ogc:Literal>
                           </ogc:Function>
                       </Size>
                       <Rotation>
                          <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
                               <!-- Value to transform -->
                               <ogc:Function name="sqrt">
                                <ogc:Add>
                                    <ogc:Mul>
                                      <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                                      <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    </ogc:Mul>
                                    <ogc:Mul>
                                      <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                                      <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                                    </ogc:Mul>
                                </ogc:Add>
                              </ogc:Function>

                               <!-- Output values and thresholds -->
                               <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
                               <ogc:Literal>1.543333332</ogc:Literal>
                                <!-- <ogc:Function name="toDegrees">-->
                           <ogc:Sub>
                             <ogc:Literal>270</ogc:Literal>
                             <ogc:Div>
                             <ogc:Mul>
                            <ogc:Function name="atan2">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>v</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>u</ogc:PropertyName>
                           
                         </ogc:Function>
                               <ogc:Literal>180</ogc:Literal>
                               </ogc:Mul>
                                       <ogc:Literal>3.14159265</ogc:Literal>
                             </ogc:Div>
                                  </ogc:Sub>
                          </ogc:Function>
                          <!--</ogc:Function>-->
                     </Rotation>
                  </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
               <PointSymbolizer>
                  <Graphic>
                     <Mark>
                       <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                        <Fill>
                           <CssParameter name="fill">
                              <ogc:Literal>#ff0000</ogc:Literal>
                           </CssParameter>
                        </Fill>
                     </Mark>
                     <Size>3</Size>
                  </Graphic>
               </PointSymbolizer>
            </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

How can I limit the points to display?

Answer (score 1):

Typically you want to reduce the number of points extracted from the raster progressively, based on the current scale.

See the approach suggested in this training material, leveraging the scale parameter of the rendering transform in combination with the current scale denominator:
https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/educational/en/multidim/accessing_multidim/rtx/currents.html

Comment: Grazie Andrea. I don't understand how it works.. I added the <ogc:Function name="Categorize"><ogc:Function name="env"> etc... but i don't see any difference.. could you please clarify me how it works? Thanks again for your support